# Guice: bind to an implementation type that is bound to something else?

Tags: guice

When someone asks for a `Thing`, I want to give them a `LegacyThing`. But if they ask for a `@Modern Thing` then I want to give them `Thing` itself.

This doesn't work:

```
bind(Thing.class).to(LegacyThing.class);
bind(Thing.class).annotatedWith(Modern.class).to(Thing.class);
```

because the second binding links to the first binding, instead of directly to `Thing`.

How do I bind to `Thing` as an implementation, rather than a link to another binding?

I don't want to instantiate `Thing` myself, because it has a lot of dependencies that I want the injector to deal with. I'd also rather not subclass it or extract an interface from it, as that will also be messy.

The best idea I've come up with is to use a constructor binding, but it feels hacky:

```
bind(Thing.class)
    .annotatedWith(Modern.class)
    .toConstructor((Constructor<Thing>) InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(Thing.class)
                                                      .getMember());
```

Comment: Your approach is pretty much the only way that will work (except for using a custom `Provider`, which is worse).

Comment: Well, another approach would be to refactor so that `Thing` is abstract, and has `LegacyThing` and `ModernThing` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method providers to do so. You say you don't want to create instance yourself, but on the other hand, you already have done that hard job when you called `super()` in `LegacyThing`. Just copy/paste. Or inject the fields directly.

```java
import com.google.inject.*;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

public class Test {

  static class Dependency {}
  static class Thing {
    @Inject Thing(Dependency dependency) {}
  }
  static class LegacyThing extends Thing {
    @Inject LegacyThing(Dependency dependency) { super(dependency); }
  }
  static class Holder {
    @Inject @Modern Thing modern;
    @Inject Thing legacy;
  }

  @BindingAnnotation
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
  static @interface Modern { }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Holder holder = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
      @Provides @Modern Thing provideModernThing(Dependency dependency) {
        return new Thing(dependency);
      }
      @Provides Thing provideLegacyThing(Dependency dependency) {
        return new LegacyThing(dependency);
      }
      @Override protected void configure() {
        bind(Dependency.class).in(Singleton.class);
      }
    }).getInstance(Holder.class);
    System.out.printf("Modern: %s%n", holder.modern.getClass().getName());
    System.out.printf("Legacy: %s%n", holder.legacy.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> Modern: Test$Thing
> Legacy: Test$LegacyThing
> ```